# power series expansion of holomorphic function self-composes to the identity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I struggle with the following problem that I came across dealing with discontinuous group actions on Riemann surfaces.

Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be a domain that contains $0$ and $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function with the power series expansion $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iz^i$ at $z=0$. The function satifies $f(0)=0$, i.e. $a_0 = 0$, and there exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_k:=\underbrace{f\circ...\circ f}_{k\text{-times}}\neq\operatorname{Id}$ for $k=1,...,n-1$ and $f_n=\operatorname{Id}$.

**Prove or disprove the following**: $a_k=0$ for all $k>1$ and $a_1$ is a $n$-th root of unity.

Surely $a_1$ is a primitive root of unity.

If $f$ was a polynomial, the rest would be easy too (although I have a feeling that it is easy either way and I'm just blind): if $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^m a_iz^i$, then the leading coefficient of $f_n$ would be a power of $a_m$ and equal to zero, so $a_m=0$, and by induction the same follows for all coefficients.

With $f$ not being a polynomial, I thought I could start computing the second coefficient of $f_m$ and show that $a_2=0$ and so on. However, the second coefficients is, if I'm correct, $a_2\sum_{j=m-1}^{2m-2}a^j$. Since $a_1$ must be a primitve $n$-th root of unity, the sum is equal to the sum of all $n$-th roots of unity and hence 0. Thus the second coefficient of $f_n$ is zero independent of what $a_2$ is. Same for the third coefficient.

I feel like computing coefficients won't help here and some other (maybe geometric) tool is needed, but I can't think of one that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why my question gets downvoted, i'm new here - can someone explain?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Ok, I added some explanation and thoughts of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $g(z):=\frac{1}{z}$ has the iteration property at $z=1$. Move it to $z=0$ and you'll get a counterexample: $f(z):=\frac{1}{1+z}-1$.

If we require that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ we have two cases:

1. If $f$ is polynomial. @mgns showed that $f$ is linear.
2. If $f$ isn't polynomial we have an essential singularity at $\infty$. In particular $f$ isn't injective and we get $\text{id}\neq f\circ\cdots\circ f$. Therefore this case isn't possible.